# Как удалить дубликаты в списке словарей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict, дублирование

Есть список словарей вида:

```
surv = [
    {'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?', 'description': 'Убийца'},
    {'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?', 'description': 'Убийца'},
    {'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'},
    {'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'}
]
```

Каким образом я могу оставить уникальные значения?

Comment: это список словарей?

Comment: Да, это список словарей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно так:

```
>>> new = [dict(s) for s in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in surv)]
>>> new
[{'id': 1, 'description': 'Убийца', 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?'}, {'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'id': 2, 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'}]
```

или вот так:

```
>>> new = map(dict, set(tuple(sorted(e.items())) for e in surv))
>>> print(*new)
{'description': 'Убийца', 'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?'} {'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу', 'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?'}
```

Comment: твоя мысль про список словарей подтолкнула меня к решению, но все равно спасибо!

Comment: `set` логичен, но после него поля в словарях перемешиваются

Answer (score 3):

Так, например:

```
print(*{x['id']: x for x in surv}.values(), sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?', 'description': 'Убийца'}
{'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ответ полезен

Answer (score 1):

```
surv = [
    {'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?', 'description': 'Убийца'},
    {'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?', 'description': 'Убийца'},
    {'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'},
    {'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'}
]
transform = list(set(map(str, surv)))
print(transform[0] + '\n' + transform[1])
```

Вывод:

```
{'id': 1, 'title': 'Кто убил Цезаря?', 'description': 'Убийца'}
{'id': 2, 'title': 'Сколько лет Йоге?', 'description': 'Вопрос про Йогу'}
```

Comment: То, что словари в результате превратились в строки - не очень хорошо. Возможно, автор вопроса хочет их потом использовать не только для печати.